# how can I pass subset of rows to custom function and return a list?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have this function which just returns me the applied arguments and the default arguments:

```
def pattern(ch1=False,ch2=False,ch3=False,ch4=False):
    return [ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4]

x = pattern(ch4=True)
x

Out[77]:

[0, 0, 0, True]
```

How could I apply the above function on a subset of rows with the arguments from the "channel" column of the following DataFrame.

```
  df1 = pd.DataFrame({"sample":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                    "channel":["ch1","ch2","ch3","ch4",
                              "ch1","ch2","ch3","ch4"
                              ],
                    "available":[True,True,True,True,
                            False,False,False,False,
                            ]
                    })
df1 = df1.set_index("sample")
df1
```

Let's say I want to pass row index 1 to 2 which should set the ch1 & ch2 parameter to True and return **[True,True,False,False]**

2nd example would be to pass row 4 to 5. This should return **[True,False,False,False]**

Comment: looks like `pandas.DataFrame.apply`

Comment: Try `pattern(ch1=df1.loc[1, 'available'], ch2=df1.loc[2, 'available'])`.

Comment: @ResidentSleeper: I tried your Code and it works but I prefer the Code of josemz as it let me slice the rows and pass them to the function but thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option:

```py
pattern(**dict(zip(df1.loc[:2].channel, df1.loc[:2].available)))
# [True, True, False, False]

pattern(**dict(zip(df1.loc[4:6].channel, df1.loc[4:6].available)))
# [False, False, False, True]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your code it works like I wanted it! I didn't know that I can pass key:value pair with zip function. That is very cool!!